# associative container references

Tags: c++, c++11

When using an associative container, I've observed, that at least sometimes a series of:

```
container[key].field1 = something1;
container[key].field2 = something2;
container[key].field3 = something3;
```

produces a smaller binary (executable) than, say

```
auto& c(container[key]);

c.field1 = something1;
c.field2 = something2;
c.field3 = something3;
```

I am confused. AFAIK, a value would need to be looked up for every `container[key] = ...` statement. Does the compiler optimize these lookups away? What is the best thing to do?

Comment: which compiler and what compiler options?

Comment: What do you mean by "smaller"? You mean the number of bytes of executable code produced?

Comment: You should provide a complete example that compiles (so we can verify your observations) and also provide the sizes of your executables for both versions.

Comment: The "best things to do" is to avoid generalizing! Well.. at least usually.

Comment: If the compiler can prove that `container[key]` will return the same result all three times, then it can transform the first snippet into the second. This is definitely doable in principle, but C++ compilers just don't quite go there yet, it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"What is the best thing to do?"

The best thing to do is to not look at such details, since tomorrow (or whenever the next version of the compiler, library or coffee machine is released) everything will be different anyway.

In the end, the "best thing to do" is to write code that

- is readable
- maintainable
- self-documenting
- works

So, compare your solutions and keep the one that "feels better" or "looks better". I would probably keep the one that does just one lookup, as it emphasises the fact that everything happens on the same object.

Comment: That may not be the case for code with other requirements than those you mention.